# How to create .NET "System.Windows.Clipboard"?

Tags: .netlink, clipboard

I have followed the instructions for creating a blank .Net form and it works.

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];
myform = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.Form"];
ShowNETWindow[myform];
(* Don't forget to release it later *)
ReleaseNETObject[myform];
```

However, I cannot get a reference to `"System.Windows.Clipboard"`.

```
clipboard = NETNew["System.Windows.Clipboard"]
```

> NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.TypeLoadException: Type System.Windows.Clipboard not found.
>      at Wolfram.NETLink.TypeLoader.GetType(String typeName, String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnError)
>      at Wolfram.NETLink.Internal.CallPacketHandler.loadType1(KernelLinkImpl ml).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, we must load the *PresentationCore* assembly to make the type [System.Windows.Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) available:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];

LoadNETAssembly["PresentationCore"];
```

Second, `System.Windows.Clipboard` is a static class so it cannot be instantiated using `NETNew`.  We must import its static members instead:

```
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Clipboard", AllowShortContext -> False];
```

Now, we can access the clipboard through static members such as [GetText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597033(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
CopyToClipboard["hi there"]

System`Windows`Clipboard`GetText[]
(* "hi there" *)
```

Comment: Very nice. (+1)  Holding out for more just in case.